# Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 stuck on boot after install

Tags: boot, server, virtualbox

So I just installed Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 on VirtualBox, and during the install reboot, it froze at:

```
[ OK ] Reached target Cloud-init target
```

I gave it 1GB of memory, 1 core of CPU, and 500GB of storage because it is for a home server I am setting up.

Should I wait for it, shut it down the hard way, or do something else?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed the problem. For anyone with the same problem, here's what I did:

Go into "Machine" at the top in VirtualBox and press "ACPI Shutdown" then just start it again.

Comment: Thanks, same here, using Virt-Manager instead of VirtualBox.
It only hangs on that step on the very first boot.
Subsequent boots are fine.
You saved me a lot of hours (I would have waited much longer for it to come back, if I hadn't seen your answer here!)

Comment: And for VMWare you'll pick "Shut Down Guest".